# Adding a module in sugarCRM 6.5 C.E. doesn't create a corresponding folder in custom/modules

Tags: module, workflow, directory, customization, sugarcrm

I need to add a logic hook to a module built in Module Builder in SugarCRM 6.5( Community Edition ).

This logic hook should take all the fields that I have just saved after completing a form in a module and create a new record in a different module with these fields( in order to simulate a workflow ).

All the tutorials on the internet( on logic hooks ) talk about modifying stuff in "./custom/Extension/modules//..." but, after creating and deploying a module in sugarCRM, I do NOT have my module present in either "./custom/Extension/modules/" or "./custom/modules" .

Thank you for your time,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those directories are for customizations and extensions like *studio* changes and custom code like hooks.

That those directories are not present only means that there are no customizations yet, so feel free to create those folders and add your hook inside.

Make sure that you create the directories with the correct names (as stated in the tutorials), including the correct case for all letters.

Also don't forget to give the web-process ownership/write-permissions to the all folders you create in *custom*, otherwise Sugar might fail to save *studio* changes and aggregation files at some point in the future.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I think the module's corresponding folder name is the module's label. I'll try what you said and feedback on it.

Comment: the module's corresponding folder name is the same as in the `modules/` directory, so usually `packageprefix_Modulename`

Comment: yes that's right. I have added logichooks.ext.php in "./custom/Extension/modules/<module_name>/" but apparently to no avail.

Comment: Afterwards I added logic_hooks.php in ./custom/modules/<module_name>/Ext/" and apparently the after save logic hook WORKED!!!